# Word Interop 12: SaveAs new filename without dialog

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am writing a Windows Explorer extension that opens an existing .docx file, edits a few things, and saves it to a different path and name.  It successfully opens the file, but when it hits the `document.SaveAs()` command it just opens the Save As dialog with the original filename and path, rather than saving to the new path.

Here is the code section that handles the doc.

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
application.Visible = true;

var document = application.Documents.Open(
    FileName: reviewRecordTemplatePath,
    AddToRecentFiles: false,
    Visible: true);

// Do stuff...

document.SaveAs(FileName: reviewRecordPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a copy of the document before you open it?

For example, lets say you're going to modify c:\docs\myfile.docx using your script, and you want to save the modified version as c:\newdocs\newfile.docx.

Before opening Word in your script, do a File.Move("c:\docs\myfile.docx", "c:\newdocs\newfile.docx"); and then open the target file, make your changes, and do a document.Save();

Comment: *facepalm*  I got so fixed on getting SaveAs to work, I didn't think about the obvious solution.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the filename and fileformat for the [SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Document class.

Comment: SaveAs2() isn't available, only SaveAs() and SaveAsQuickStyleSet().  Is that because I am using an older Interop interface?  (12)